# Can't Get BarChart to use ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to get a `BarChart` to colour negative valued bars red and positive valued bars green but I'm having a time trying to do it.  My latest attempt is:

```
data = {0.34`, 0.04`, 1.07`, -0.54`, -2.4`, 0.44`};
t = Piecewise[{{# >= 0, Green}}, Red] &;
BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stepped", BarSpacing -> None,
 ColorFunction -> t, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

However this still colours the bars in the default colour. May someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I thought this would be pretty simple. I'm not getting an error.  It just is ignoring the `ColorFunction`. I'm on 10.0.1

Thanks,

Edmund

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have inverted `Piecewise` arguments. Here is the right form:

```
data = {0.34, 0.04, 1.07, -0.54, -2.4, 0.44};
color=Piecewise[{{Green,# >= 0}}, Red] &;
BarChart[data
        ,ChartLayout -> "Stepped"
        ,BarSpacing -> None
        ,ColorFunction -> color
        ,ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    ]
```

Now it works:

[image]

I personaly prefer `Which`. Here is an example for accumulated color change using it:

```
color=Which[#<= 0,Red,True,Green]&;
BarChart[data
        ,ChartLayout -> "Stepped"
        ,BarSpacing -> None
        ,ChartStyle->color/@Accumulate@data
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the last bar green ?

Comment: @Murta Thanks, that works great. But do you know why `Piecewise` isn't working?  Shouldn't it work the same as `Which`? Also, I prefer `Piecewise` as it is not a programming construct as `Which` is.

Comment: @Murta Why is the fourth bar red and the last one green ?

Comment: @eldo, it's a positive variation. So, it's green...

Comment: Why downvote? Someone knows?

Comment: @murta The OP seems to be happy, so let me upvote another of your answers :)

Comment: @Murta Oh! How foolish of me. LOL! And the Total Noob award goes to ...  LOL!  Thanks!  The `Accumulate` version is nice as well but your first answer with focusing on the value of the bar is definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: @Edmund not for that. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Murta Sorry, I missunderstood.

Comment: @eldo no problem